Non-finitely generated abelian groups of the form $G/Z(G)$
Let $G$ be a group and let $Z(G)$ denote its centre. A group $H$ is called capable if there exists $G$ such that $H = G/Z(G)$. Baer classified all capable finitely generated abelian groups. Modern research on capable group seems to mainly cover finite groups.
I would like to know what non-finitely generated abelian groups are capable. What about $\mathbb Q$ or profinite groups like $\mathbb Z_p$ or $\widehat{\mathbb Z}$?

Doesn't answer your question, but note that Baer characterized all capable groups that are direct sums of cyclic groups, whether or not they are finitely generated.

Observation:   for this we need $G'\le Z(G).$

@non-euclideangeometry If $N\subseteq Z(G)$ and $G/N$ is nilpotent of class $k$, then $G$ is nilpotent of class at most $k+1$. In particular, if $G/N$ is abelian (nilpotent of class at most $1$), then $G$ is nilpotent of class at most $2$ ($G'\leq Z(G)$).

I haven't thought about the $p$-adics or $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$, but it is known that $\mathbb{Q}$, and more generally any group in which every finitely generated subgroup is cyclic, cannot be capable.
Suppose $A$ is a (necessarily abelian) nontrivial group in which every finitely generated subgroup is cyclic, and that $G$ is a group and $N\subseteq Z(G)$ a subgroup such that $G/N\cong A$.  I claim that $G$ is abelian, and therefore $N\neq Z(G)$.
Let $x,y\in G$. Then $\langle xN,yN\rangle$ is a finitely generated subgroup of $G/N$, so there exists $z\in G$ such that $\langle zN\rangle = \langle xN,yN\rangle$. In particular, there exist integer $a,b$ and central elements $n,m$ such that $x=z^an$ and $y=z^bn$. But that means that $x$ and $y$ commute:
$$xy = z^anz^bm = z^az^bnm = z^bz^amn = z^bmz^an = yx.$$
Therefore, $G$ is abelian.
In particular, $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ are not capable.

This is nice. If $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic then $G$ is abelian. If $G/Z(G)$ is locally cyclic then $G$ is locally abelian, but locally abelian is the same thing as abelian.
